# i want to fetch data on select2 drop down using ajax but i am not getting how to fetch data for update view

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

plz help me someone. I dont have any idea how to fetch data on select2 drop down also for multiple.I have tried this in my script

```
                    $('#edit_question1').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                     $('#edit_question2').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                     $('#edit_question3').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                     $('#edit_question4').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                     $('#edit_question5').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question6').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question7').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question8').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question9').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question10').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question11').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
                    $('#edit_question12').val(response.qry1.data[i].parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your ajax function here and also check in console the response of your ajax call.